# Unload data from SnowFlake into ADLS

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to unload data from SnowFlake (running on Azure) in ADLS.

The File gets created but it is of type "octet-stream".

Below is example of what i am running.

```
COPY INTO @PARQUET_STG/snowflake/data_share
FROM TABLE 
file_format = 'PARQUET_FORMAT';
```

I even tried

```
file_format = (type 'parquet') and file_format = (type 'csv')
```

but same results.

Can someone point out what is missing here?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message that is seen for this case.

Comment: How did you determine that it is "octet-stream" file, because no file extension? Can you share the output of "list @ PARQUET_STG" after COPY INTO command?